# Mysql multiple tables

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-tables

I have 5 tables containg products and one table containg the order.

```
 CREATE TABLE `Prod1` (
  `idProd1` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `price` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProd1`));
```

This is model for one table. I have 5 like this one.

In the 6 i have foreign key all the primary key from the products table 
I want to create a select to give me the total to pay.

The problem is if one of the key is null is returning me the total from all the tables.

This is what i have ti'll now.

```
select p1.idprod1,p2.idprod2,p3.idprod3,p4.idprod4,p5.idprod5, sum(p1.idprod1+p2.idprod2+p3.idprod3+p4.idprod4+p5.idprod5)
from prod1 p1,prod2 p2,prod3 p3,prod4 p4,prod5 p5,order o
where p1.idprod1=o.iprod1 and p2.idprod2=o.idprod2 and p3.idprod3=o.idprod3 and p4.idprod=o.idprod4 and p5.idprod5=o.idprod5 and 
                o.idorder=(select max(idorder) from order);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `where p1.idprod1=o.iprod1 and p2.idprod2=o.idprod2 and p3.idprod3=o.idprod3 and p4.idprod=o.idprod4 and p5.idprod5=o.idprod5` I don't see any reason to return `p1.idprod1,p2.idprod2,p3.idprod3,p4.idprod4,p5.idprod5`.

Other note what is the reason to `sum(p1.idprod1+p2.idprod2+p3.idprod3+p4.idprod4+p5.idprod5)`?

I think the only column we can `SUM` is the `price`.

So my approach is:

```
SELECT 
  o.*,
  sum(p1.price+p2.price+p3.price+p4.price+p5.price)
FROM order o
LEFT JOIN prod1 p1
ON p1.idprod1=o.iprod1
LEFT JOIN prod2 p2
p2.idprod2=o.idprod2
LEFT JOIN prod3 p3
ON p3.idprod3=o.idprod3 
LEFT JOIN prod4 p4
ON p4.idprod=o.idprod4
LEFT JOIN prod5 p5
ON p5.idprod5=o.idprod5
WHERE o.idorder=(select max(idorder) from order)
GROUP BY o.idorder
```

Comment: If i have an id null doesn't do the sum anymore.
The sum on the price. I've made a mistake there with the id's

Answer (score 0):

I used Alex idea and improved a little. 
I selected and the names from my products. in the same manner, ifnull(p1.name,"-"), etc. And if a id is null is returning me for the name dash "-" and for the price 0. Maybe it will help somebody.

```
SELECT 
  o.*,
  sum(ifnull(p1.price,0)+ifnull(p2.price,0)+
        ifnull(p3.price,0)+ifnull(p4.price,0)+ifnull(p5.price,0))
FROM order o
LEFT JOIN prod1 p1
ON p1.idprod1=o.iprod1
LEFT JOIN prod2 p2
p2.idprod2=o.idprod2
LEFT JOIN prod3 p3
ON p3.idprod3=o.idprod3 
LEFT JOIN prod4 p4
ON p4.idprod=o.idprod4
LEFT JOIN prod5 p5
ON p5.idprod5=o.idprod5
WHERE o.idorder=(select max(idorder) from order)
GROUP BY o.idorder
```